# How to deploy my app Laravel 9 Vue 3 Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

Hi I have a question about deploying my laravel vue app with vite.
The problem is the following:
At the time of running

```
npm run build
```

my files are created in a build folder, so far so normal but when I visit my app in production the url of my app with vue is placed like this

```
http://appdomain.com/build/
```

and if I reload the page the app is completely broken, it only reloads if I visit the url of the domain.
[][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exc40.png

This bothers me a bit because with webpack it was super simple, with vite I have done many configurations but still the same.